# passing a nested structure to a function

Tags: c, function, struct

The way I'm going about this seems to not be optimal to me. Although my code is working, I feel like I'm missing something I could optimize or do a different way, a simpler way.

My structs:

```
typedef struct {
    char nom[30];
    char prenom[30];
    double salary;
    double taxes;
} employee;

typedef struct {
    char nom[20];
    employee *employee_list;
    unsigned int nmbr_employees;
} company;
```

The important parts of my code:

```
int main()
{
    unsigned int nmbr_companies, nmbr_emps, i,j;
    scanf("%u", &nmbr_companies);
    company *company_list = malloc(sizeof(company) * nmbr_companies);

    for(i=0; i <nmbr_companies; i++){
        scanf("%u", &nmbr_emps);
        company_list[i].employee_list = malloc(sizeof(employee) * nmbr_emps);
        for(j=0; j < nmbr_emps; j++){
            calc_netsalary(&company_list[i].employee_list[j]); // [1]
        }
    }

}

double calc_netsalary(employe *emp_list) // [2]
{
    double salary;
    if(emp_list->salary > 75000){
        emp_list->taxes = 750;
        salary=something;
        }
    return salary;
}
```

[1] I'm wondering if there's an optimal way of of passing a similar nested struct to a function, and any pitfalls I should pay attention to when doing it the way I have.

[2] I thought I understood pointers until I got to structures, and it all got confusing again for me. Any insightful comments on how to deal with similar structures in the future without scratching my head and second guessing myself would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is fine. I don't understand the problem you have with understanding the pointers. A struct is just a block of memory with a defined (fixed) layout. A pointer to a struct thus points to a block of memory with such a fixed layout. When you access a member of a structure, the compiler will just add the offset of the member to the base adresss of the structure. So nmbr_employees is at [start of structure in memory] + 20 characters (=20 bytes) + 1 integer (= 4 bytes).

What you call "list" is actually an array, so better give it such a name. (You allocate nmbr_emps times a block of memory with a defined lay-out, layed out neatly one after the other.) As they are neatly layed out one after the other, you can address them using array notation.

To optimize the access, you can use pointers and write:

```
company *pCompany= company_list;
for(i=0; i <nmbr_companies; i++, pCompany++){
    scanf("%u", &nmbr_emps);
    pCompany->employee_list = malloc(sizeof(employee) * nmbr_emps);
    employee *pEmp= pCompany->employee_list;
    for(j=0; j < nmbr_emps; j++, pEmp++){
        // you should now first read-in the emp's data
        calc_netsalary(pEmp); // [1]
    }
}
```

The C compiler will increment the pCompany and pEmp pointers with the size of their struct in the "++" expressions.